# Need help to retrieve a google doc info in Javascript (i'm a Newbi)

Tags: javascript

I am creating a code to display the price of products whose price is regularly updated via a spreadsheet of google doc.

Would anyone know if it is possible in javascript to automatically retrieve the price displayed in a specific cell of the excel table?

I should then display only 60% of the price, so I think I should write something like this:

`<font class="fontpricestyle">{{ ProductPriceFromSpreadsheetCell | times: 0.6| round: 0 }} €</font>`

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ciNi9ZQ3q1ojUoy47q2DVWqwOmSNfljuzH2QBe91o74/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes you'll have to use the googleapis from here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, it is possible!

I suggest you take a look at the [Sheets API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) first.

Since you want to retrieve a value from a specific cell, you can make the following request:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{yourRange}
```

Where `spreadsheetId` is the id of the **spreadsheet** you are using and `yourRange` is the range of the cell wanted.

The response of the above request will return a [`ValueRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#resource:-valuerange) resource and the actual value of the range will be depicted in the `values` field.

You can also use the [Sheets API Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) in order to simulate the requests wanted and get a better glimpse of the requests, parameters and the responses.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Values:get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get);
- [Sheets API Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js);
- [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest).